# How to show horiziontal line after each row in ng-grid of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the ng-grid in angular js. How can we show the horizontal line after each row in the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have created a  [view](http://plnkr.co/edit/galoo55bJhWemz3fin7V?p=preview) which is actually css manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the rowTemplate attribute in your gridOptions object and add a line with css/html